# store uploaded file with user id name

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a folder in my img folder! users avatar img is supposed to go there! The issue is I want to save the pics with the user id name. For example user with id 1 has a pic named 1.jpg so i should rename the file $id. The problem is file extensions are removed! Look at the code below:

```
$target_file = basename(time().$_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
```

How should I change this line for my purpose? I want this:
If user with id 1 uploads avatar.png it stores in folder with the name 1.png (I will encode the id later).

Also, imagine i already have a variable which have user id ready called $id.

Comment: `$target_file ='your/file/path/'.$id.'.png';`

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];

$ext = pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

**$ext** is the extension, while
`"$userid.$ext"` gives you `UserID.extension`

Comment: it gives you extension.username

Comment: @TobiasKun typo, you had to give me -1 for that?

Comment: Yes. Because it did not helped him in this state. I removed the -1. Altough you should check your answer again. He wants to use the user id.

Answer (score 0):

Do you thought about something like this?

```
$userID = 1;
$path = "/absolute/path/to/your/upload/folder/";
//explode the filename so we get the extension
$fileData = explode(".", $_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
//considering the filename "avatar.png" $target_file will contain "/absolute/path/to/your/upload/folder/1.png"
$target_file = $path . $userID . "." . $fileData[1]);
```